# Python rounding error and import Decimal don't work

Tags: python, linux

need to calculate with decimals but python show error, but the solution that the book give, don't work!!!

By example if try to sum 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 show the classical error but if try:

```
from decimal import Decimal
d = Decimal(0.1)
d + d + d
```

The error obtained is:

```
Decimal('0.3000000000000000166533453694')
```

what's supposed the solution gives an error, please help, using python 3.8 in openSuse TumbleWeed.

[Image of the python fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/791yO.png)

My question is different from the post [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken), that post dont ask about  "decimal" library.

Comment: Please show the output as text, not as a screenshot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: "The error obtained is..." This is not an error. It is the output of a successful calculation. This works exactly as it is supposed to. See the link above for details about why you don't get exactly `0.3` as you probably expect.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice that post is not the same, my issue is about de Decimal library and that post you share don't ask about such library.

Comment: It is the same because you initialize the `Decimal` object with a floating point value.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice in that post the solution is if (abs(x - y) < myToleranceValue) { ... }, I don't understend how that can help me.

Comment: To clarify, the **cause** is the same as in that post. The behavior you see here is due to the fact that **floating point numbers are not real numbers (in the mathematical sense)**. Rather, floats are an approximation to the real numbers. As such, they have quirky behaviors that all programmers should be aware of.

Comment: I shared the link so you can read about why this happens rather than giving a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output you see is not an error. Since you initialize `Decimal()` with a float value, it uses float arithmetic. On the other hand, if you do

```
d2 = Decimal('0.1')
print(d2 + d2 + d2)
```

You will get the result you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, you can also adjust the precision with `getcontext().prec`

```
from decimal import *

getcontext().prec = 100   # Set a new precision
b = Decimal(0.1)
c = Decimal("0.1")

print(b+b+b)
print(c+c+c)

# 0.3000000000000000166533453693773481063544750213623046875
# 0.3
```